# Many errors during compiling opencv_contrib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, opencv-contrib

I have a trouble - I want to compile opnecv with opencv_contrib. I use Visual Studio 2013, last version cmake, opencv and opencv_contrib from github but... suddenly I can't.

I did it in past, according to this tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/tutorial_dnn_build.html
and everything was fine, but now compilator show more than 100 fatal errors.

First and second errors look this:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '__m128i' to '__m128'    
error C2660: '_mm256_insertf128_ps' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

The rest are similar to this:

```
error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\opencv_root\build_opencv\modules\core\opencv_core_AVX2.dir\Release\mathfuncs_core.avx2.obj'
```

List of my activities:

- download sorce code from github
- run cmake, choose source code, choose destination folder, set path to 'extra modules', generatre
- run OpenCV.sln, choose "release", select ALLBUILD, click "build" (like on screen)   [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9O87.png)

I tried x32 and x64 version, tried to compile it with and without opencv_contrib modules, but this still won't work.

Where to find a solution, when I make a mistake?
Help, please :)

Regards!

Comment: is it 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: I have tried x64 and x32 versions, but the problem has already been solved

Answer (score 0):

There is an `OpenCV 3.2.0` with `opencv_contib` binary for 64-bit Windows available in github. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/CCM2016/opencv). It's complied with Visual Studio 2015 and requires `.Net Framework 4.5` or above that you can download it separately from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=30653) before installing it.

Hope this would save your time to get the `opencv_contrib` and make it works.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
Unfortunately, from opencv_contrib I need only arUCO module, but this compilation as I can see not include it

Comment: Have you installed it and checked? For python, type (1) `import numpy as np`, (2) `import cv2` and (3) `help(cv2.aruco)` that tells **ArUco** is there.. For C++, the header files, `charuco.hpp` & `dictionary.hpp`, are in `C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0\include\opencv2\aruco` directory.

Comment: In fact i haven't installed it, just looked on surface, looking for aruco folder. Thanks for link, but I did not want to use precompiled libraries

I worked hard and I found solution my problem. On CMake I had to changed CPU_BASELINE and CPU_DISPATCH from SSSE3 to SSE2. After this changed everything worked fine